# Sorting order items by SKU in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sorting, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I am trying to **order the products by sku within an order in an email** in **Woocommerce**.

I have not had any luck with the following code.

Some help? Thanks since now!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_items', function( $items, $order ) {
    uasort( $items,
        function( $a, $b ) {
            return strnatcmp( $a['_sku'], $b['_sku'] );
        }
    );
    return $items;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Sample sort result:

- INFSTRAW I
- NFMUFFIN
- INFFLORES
- INFTAFLOR
- INFTAPINK
- CTEPINK4
- CTECAKE4
- INFCHOCO
- UCUBTOMA

Comment: _"I have not had any luck"_ is not a problem description. Why not? What happened, instead of what you wanted to happen?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it well. I added a detail of how they appear ordered ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated On July 2020**

Here is the way to do it:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_items', 'filter_order_get_items_by_sku', 10, 3 );
function filter_order_get_items_by_sku( $items, $order, $types ) {
    if( count($items) > 1 ) {
        $item_skus = $sorted_items = array();

        // Loop through order line items
        foreach( $items as $items_id => $item ){
            // Check items type: for versions before Woocommerce 3.3
            if( $item->is_type('line_item') && method_exists( $item, 'get_product' ) ){
                $product = $item->get_product(); // Get the product Object
                if( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
                    $item_skus[$product->get_sku()] = $items_id;
                }
            }
        }

        // Only for line items when our sku array is not empty
        if( ! empty($item_skus) ) {
            // Sorting in ASC order based on SKUs;
            ksort($item_skus); // or use krsort() for DESC order

            // Loop through sorted $item_skus array
            foreach( $item_skus as $sku => $item_id ){
                // Set items in the correct order
                $sorted_items[$item_id] = $items[$item_id];
            }
            $items = $sorted_items;
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> This will sort items by sku order ASC on backend and frontend orders and in email notifications

---

Also sorting items once the order is placed before data is saved to the database, could be a better way to do it.

Comment: I am getting this error in some old orders: Call to a member function get_sku() on boolean Any idea? Thanks

Comment: @jpussacq That means that your database has not been updated correctly for WC version 3+, on this old orders.

Comment: What can i do??

Comment: @jpussacq I had never got this problem yet, so I don't have the answer right now. How old are those orders?

Comment: There is something very strange. The error is not generated in the test environment, which is a copy of the production process.

Comment: @jpussacq May be because you have still enabled the debug on production. Or the php is in verbose mode on production.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @LoicTheAztec I've added the following check in the code:

```
if ($product instanceof WC_Product) {
                    $item_skus[$product->get_sku()] = $items_id;
                }
```

This prevents an error on the front-end customer orders page.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_items', 'filter_order_get_items_by_sku', 10, 3 );
function filter_order_get_items_by_sku( $items, $order, $types ) {
    if( count($items) > 1 ) {
        $item_skus = $sorted_items = array();

        // Loop through order line items
        foreach( $items as $items_id => $item ){
            // Check items type: for versions before Woocommerce 3.3
            if( $item->is_type('line_item') ){
                $product = $item->get_product(); // Get the product Object
                
                if ($product instanceof WC_Product) {
                    $item_skus[$product->get_sku()] = $items_id;
                }
            }
        }

        // Only for line items when our sku array is not empty
        if( ! empty($item_skus) ) {
            // Sorting in ASC order based on SKUs;
            ksort($item_skus); // or use krsort() for DESC order

            // Loop through sorted $item_skus array
            foreach( $item_skus as $sku => $item_id ){
                // Set items in the correct order
                $sorted_items[$item_id] = $items[$item_id];
            }
            $items = $sorted_items;
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```