# Sorting orders in backend based on SKU

Tags: wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, hook

I am trying to sort orders added manually by sku.

I've tried all these codes:
[Sort order items by SKU in Woocommerce admin order pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54797925/sort-order-items-by-sku-in-woocommerce-admin-order-pages) 
[Sorting order items via a hooked function in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55856483/sorting-order-items-via-a-hooked-function-in-woocommerce/55857557)
[Sorting order items by SKU in Woocommerce email notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046272/sorting-order-items-by-sku-in-woocommerce-email-notifications)

Underneath code is working to sort by name.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'sortOrderItemsSKU', 10, 2);
function sortOrderItemsSKU($items, $order) {
    uasort( $items,
        function( $a, $b ) {
            return strcmp( $a['name'], $b['name'] );
        }
    );
    return $items;
}
```

But when changing to _sku / sku both not working.

```
function( $a, $b ) {
    return strcmp( $a['_sku'], $b['_sku'] );
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code can't work as woocommerce_order_status_changed is not the right hook to be used… The right hook is woocommerce_order_get_items as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50048721/3730754

Answer (score -1):

I did find another solution. It returns the sorted array, but somehow the items in the order aren't being sorted:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'process_offline_order', 10, 4 );
function process_offline_order( $order_id, $items, $order, $types = 'line_item' ){
            
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id ); 
    $items = $order->get_items(); 
    
    $item_skus = $sorted_items = array();

    foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) {
        
        $product = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] );
        $product_id = $item->get_variation_id() ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();
                    
        $product = $item->get_product(); 
        $item_skus[$product->get_sku()] = $item_id;
        
    }
    
    ksort($item_skus);

    foreach( $item_skus as $keyL => $valueL ){
        $sorted_items[$keyL] = $items[$keyL];
        $sorted_items[$valueL] = $items[$valueL];
    }

    return $item_skus;
}
```

So the problem is probably within this part:

```
foreach( $item_skus as $keyL => $valueL ){
    $sorted_items[$keyL] = $items[$keyL];
    $sorted_items[$valueL] = $items[$valueL];
}   
return $item_skus;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Wordpress Guru :)??